# Eigen cwisemin/cwisemax access violation in Visual Studio 2017 release build

Tags: c++, visual-studio, eigen, visual-studio-2017

Here is some sample code, which results in an access violation when using the x86 release build of Visual Studio 2017:

```
#include <Eigen\Core>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    Eigen::Vector3i a(1,1,1);
    Eigen::Vector3i b(10, 10, 10);

    std::cout << a.cwiseMin(b) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

x64 doesn't seem to crash, but the first value in the result is erroneous. Debug build works, as do all builds with VS 15, MinGW and Linux gcc.

cwiseMax has the same behaviour. This may be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928480/eigen-c-release-build-in-visual-studio

Does anyone know of a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same results, except vs2015 x86 release build also give me erroneous result for first value. The 2 options I have come up with are:

1. Turn off optimization. **Properties->C/C++->Optimization**
2. Store the result of `a.cwiseMin(b)` in a third variable:

   `Eigen::Vector3i c(a.cwiseMin(b));
   std::cout << c << std::endl;`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Turning off the optimization does work, but is sadly not very feasable, as it makes heaver computations too slow. While your suggestion seems to work for that example, it fails if you replace the constant values with a variable `Eigen::Vector3i a(i,i,i);`...

Comment: I don't see the problem on my end if I replace the constant with a variable, as long as the variable is initialized. `int i = 1;  Eigen::Vector3i a(i, i, i);`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and could reproduce the issue with your example-code as well. In my case, the issue disappeared after disabling vectorization by specifying the `EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE` preprocessor-define. If you want to keep the vectorization enabled, you may want to check your memory-alignment (since the vectorization has stronger alignment requirements when enabled).